# I am running this code for a discord bot and while there is no error, it is not sending the desires message even after logging in

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return

if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

client.run('your token here')

As mentioned above, I believe the issues come with the second async function or below, I tried testing it but there was no hello back. Thank you.

Comment: What desired message? Exactly how do you run the program, and what observable behaviour are you expecting as a result? Also, please make sure your code is formatted correctly, as indentation is crucial in Python. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that we are looking at properly.

Answer (score 0):

You ideally shouldn't be using `discord.Client()` here but `discord.ext.commands.Bot()`

Re-write :

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Which would result in :
[image: Result]

Also, I can't see any issues in the code you provided other than the second `if` statement being incorrectly indented but even if that were the case you'll get an error.

Comment: What is wrong with discord.Client()